# Hide a div or class element on specific pages and show on other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I would like to hide the following div/class only on few pages of my website:

```
    <div class="topNav">
    <nav id="display_menu_5" class="menu">
    ......
```

I have tried using jQuery but it didn't help, and using php I have managed to hide it on all pages, I am really hitting a brick wall here with this, how this can be done?

If it can be of any help I am doing this in a template on a ecommerce platform - Volusion, so I might be hindered by that in some way.

Comment: Have you tried making a separate js file containing jquery to hide the div and only placing it in the headers of the pages where you want to hide the div?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the headers of those pages, I can only input data into a few <body> parts

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using different files, which you include in each other.

which gives the possibility to set a variable in the php file called by the url/page like:

```
$nav_visible = true;
```

and in your nav.php file:

```
if (isset($nav_visible)) {
    echo '<div class="topNav">';
}
```

alternatively you can check if the variable is true or false instead of checking for it's existence.

Comment: I don't have access to .php documents at all, I can only access template.html and template.css files

Comment: why would you label the question with php then?

Comment: Because I used something like this in template.html:

`<?php if( !is_page('XXX') ):?>
 the code to display this div goes here.
 <?php endif;?>`

..so I thought it wasrelevant, and on a side note, it did hide te desired div, but on all pages

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I found a solution using css only. I was able to access the desired pages through Volusion description fields and I added an inline style to each page like this:

```
    <style>
    .topNav{display:none !important;}
    </style>
```